# What do you mean by file handling?

Tags: c, perl, file-io, file-handling

What does a file handling mean? What is the difference between them in different languages?, for example [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) or [c](/questions/tagged/c). I'm unable to get a grasp on the concept.

I'm posting an example from perl suggested by @jeegar patel.

`open(DATA, " <file.txt");`

if you see in this piece of snippet, DATA acts as a file handle, so what exactly is the function/purpose of  "DATA" here.

PS: I apologize if this is such a lame question, but I'm trying to get the basics right! Appreciate if anybody could acknowledge this.

Comment: This is too broad for SO. Sorry.

Comment: Note that nowadays, `open my $FH, '<', 'file.txt'` is prefered in Perl, possibly with `or die $!`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Any programming language, to perform any file operation in programming way it will have some own APIs.

Like `C` programming has.

http://www.w3schools.in/c/file-handling/

Like `perl` has

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_files.htm

> What is the difference between them in different languages?

You can read file handlings APIs for different programing language and came to know what are different in them..

Comment: in the perl document the "DATA" is a keyword/just a word where we can link the read/write/create function, if I'm not wrong @jeegar patel

Comment: @GRD see in C programing, we open any file and get file descriptor and we further talk with that file using that file descriptor only. same way in perl we open any file and get that DATA file handle  and then onwards we talk with that file using that file handle

Comment: so the file descriptor(here, it is DATA) will temporarily store the contents and once closed, the file descriptor is freed! I hope I'm making sense!@Jeegar patel

Comment: yes some what..ideally it does not store all contents but only some info required for that file address and last read/write pointer info etc. yes after closing file it gets freed.

Comment: quite getting the grasp of it, thanks a lot! @jeegar patel

Comment: @GRD Thanks in stackoverflow is upvote or Accepting answer :) anyway welcome buddy.

Comment: apparently I need 15 reputations to do either of the feedbacks ;-)

Comment: This is not really a specific answer what a file handle is in Perl. The first link gives such an answer, but the explanation should be given here.

Answer (score 1):

In fact your program does not get direct access to physical hardware and devices.  Your program has to request these as services from the operating system. In each language there is a "run time model" of what a pralooks like, things like where the stack, heap and program memory are.  The file system provided by the language is contains the routines needed to coordinate with the operating system, convert data types to the format required by your program and ways to find out the status of the file or even where to put things so the OS will actually write them out

This is complex stuff and each language and language design team has approached the problems somewhat differently.

Trust me they used to be a lot less standardized...

Answer (score 1):

There are many functions on various level of file system hierarchy in the word "File handling".

An example of file system hierarchy and functions in each level:

Handle file systems:
 Device/Disk/Directory(Folder)
  create/delete/rename/move

Handle a file:
 create/delete/rename

Handle a contents of a file:
 open/close/read/write

etc.

Each languages have corresponding functions and/or libraries/APIs for "file handling".

When you focused in certain level of hierarchy, "a contents of a file" for example, functions of that level may be comprehensible for you.

Don't to try to see broad functions in all levels at once.
That is not the way of human kind, but of god.